# Easyphp / Apache automatically changes the mime-type if the file exceeds a certain size?

Tags: apache, ckeditor, easyphp

I have a problem with ckeditor (http://ckeditor.com/) after installing it I load it's javascript file. It seems that the file is too large (about 350 kb) and easyphp changes its mime type to text/plain for no reason and loads the contents of the .js in the wrong way.

I have tested and also a html page if it exceeds 360 kb is loaded as text/plain and html code is not interpreted.

Why if a file is too large is loaded as text/plain? How can I solve this problem?

[image: Chrome development tool - text/plain]

[image: Chrome development tool - text/html]

Comment: I do not know, but is there a MIME type mapping?

Comment: yes, in the configuration file 'mime.types' of apache are mapped all MIME types and they are correct. ONLY that .js file has this problem (or each file greater than 350 kb)

Comment: Did you try to load a not-Javascript file greater than 350 KB? Did you try to divide the content of your js file into files which are smaller?

Comment: Yes and it all works perfectly, unfortunately I have to include an external plugin that I can't divide